# Is this Sharepoint/Project Server question off topic?

Tags: discussion

I was just taking a look at this question in the close review queue:  https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/15848/. I can't decide if it should be closed or not (though the OP seems kind of grumpy which isn't helping...)

Instinctively it feels off-topic to me but should it be left open as an example of 'Tool Usage in Project Management'? You could probably argue that's it's far too localized but I don't know enough about that particular situation to know how regularly people might come across the issue.

Comment: I just updated the pm-software tag with a better excerpt and a cross-reference to the tools tag to help clarify the proper usage of the tag in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally assisted in the clarification of this question. My opinion is that whilst detailed use of MS-Project to help solve PM problems, and questions about comms management in project management are all on-topic, the OP had already solved those issues and had arrived at a fully working solution; in the final analysis his question was about how to deploy his software so that it properly integrates with disparate file servers. The OP notes that if his sub-project files are all located together in either location his solution works, but the software fails to handle the case where the files are located on different servers. I concluded from this that the question is actually about software/servers setup and config in its totality and thus is off-topic for this site.

Edit: Oh I see it has been placed on hold anyway. Never mind, I'll leave this answer as a clarifying point as it may assist future assessments (or may not!)

Comment: I agree with all of this. Thanks for your thoughts. As you say, software configuration and installation should not be considered on topic here. I think I lacked the domain knowledge with Project Server to judge this one accurately.

Comment: +1 to Marv. I was on the bubble about this one, because "how to use tools" and "software configuration" can be a continuum--and a slippery slope at that. I could have been persuaded that the post was tangentially on-topic, but I think Marv's reasoning is sound in this particular case.